# How to format a number as 2.5K if a thousand in PHP? Like Facebook

Tags: php

I need to show a page views value in the format of 1K of equal to one thousand, or 1.1K, 1.2K, 1.9K etc, if its not an even thousands, otherwise if under a thousand, display normal 500, 100, 250 etc, using PHP to format the number?

I'm using:--

```
function count_number($n) {
    // first strip any formatting;
    $n = (0+str_replace(",","",$n));

    // is this a number?
    if(!is_numeric($n)) return false;

    // now filter it;
    if($n>1000000000000) return round(($n/1000000000000),1).'T';
    else if($n>1000000000) return round(($n/1000000000),1).'G';
    else if($n>1000000) return round(($n/1000000),1).'M';
    else if($n>1000) return round(($n/1000),1).'K';

    return number_format($n);
}
```

**BUT it does not work correctly...**

If my page visted **2454** times, it shows **2.5k** and if **2990**, it shows **3k**...

**How o fix that problem??**

I want to SHOW Like --> **if page visited 2454 -> how to display 2.4k and if 2990 -> 2.9k, if 3000 -> 3k etc**

**Plz help me...**

---

**Thanks @ MonkeyZeus**

**Now itz DONE...**

```
function kilo_mega_giga($n) {    

if($n >= 1000 && $n < 1000000)
{
    if($n%1000 === 0)
    {
        $formatted = ($n/1000);
    }
    else
    {
        $formatted = substr($n, 0, -3).'.'.substr($n, -3, 1);
         if(substr($formatted, -1, 1) === '0')
         {
           $formatted = substr($formatted, 0, -2);
         }
    }

    $formatted.= 'k';

} else 

if($n >= 1000000 && $n < 1000000000)
{
    if($n%1000000 === 0)
    {
        $formatted = ($n/1000000);
    }
    else
    {
        $formatted = substr($n, 0, -6).'.'.substr($n, -6, 1);
         if(substr($formatted, -1, 1) === '0')
         {
           $formatted = substr($formatted, 0, -2);
         }
    }

    $formatted.= 'M';
} else 

if($n >= 1000000000 && $n < 1000000000000)
{
    if($n%1000000000 === 0)
    {
        $formatted = ($n/1000000000);
    }
    else
    {
        $formatted = substr($n, 0, -9).'.'.substr($n, -9, 1);
         if(substr($formatted, -1, 1) === '0')
         {
           $formatted = substr($formatted, 0, -2);
         }
    }

    $formatted.= 'G';
} else

if($n >= 0 && $n < 1000)
{ 

    $formatted= $n;
} 

return $formatted;

}
```

Comment: Don't use [round()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) then, use [floor()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)... if you don't understand what they do, don't use them until you've read the PHP docs and do understand them

Comment: Round function rounds the number, what you want is a floor() function instead

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know that I did not know you mentioned me in your post. You should leave an actual comment next time and use `@MonkeyZeus`. Anyways, I see your update and your code looks good but I realize that I am missing a piece of code so please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to calculate thousands. You can use this formula to figure out the formula for millions as well.

```
$n = 2000;
$formatted = '';

if($n >= 1000 && $n < 1000000)
{
    if($n%1000 === 0)
    {
        $formatted = ($n/1000);
    }
    else
    {
        $formatted = substr($n, 0, -3).'.'.substr($n, -3, -2);

        if(substr($formatted, -1, 1) === '0')
        {
            $formatted = substr($formatted, 0, -2);
        }
    }

    $formatted.= 'k';
}

echo $formatted;
```

Also, please use curly braces, ALWAYS. Future you will thank present you.

Comment: In case that `$n` is smaller than 1000 or bigger than 999999, your code won't `echo` anything but an empty string.

Comment: @prehfeldt Thank you. What part of `You can use this to calculate thousands.` made you think that this would calculate anything other than thousands?

Comment: @XeanNeia I see your edit and it looks good. Have you tried running it through some tests? I've been using an online PHP compiler so I definitely recommend trying it out. http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you very much,, I have tested this code on writecodeonline.com/php ..and it worked like a charm. thanks again..

Comment: @XeanNeia you're welcome. I do see another improvement though. You can change `$formatted = substr($n, 0, -3).'.'.substr($n, -3, -2);` into `$formatted = substr($n, 0, -3).'.'.substr($n, -3, 1);` and use -6,1 for mega and -9,1 for giga. Glad to hear it's working for you!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks again... plz see my edit... any other improvement required?

Comment: @XeanNeia Looks fine to me, I just hope you're testing it for all edge-case scenarios.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah I have tested... OK now itz done... Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

What about number greater than 10000

```
function facebookFormattter($digit) {
    if ($digit >= 1000000000) {
        return round($digit/ 1000000000, 1). 'G';
    }
    if ($digit >= 1000000) {
        return round($digit/ 1000000, 1).'M';
    }
    if ($digit >= 1000) {
        return round($digit/ 1000, 1). 'K';
    }
    return $digit;
}
```